# How can I make docker-compose on Windows respect my terminal size?

Tags: windows, terminal, docker-compose

I'm running Docker on Windows:

```
❯ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.12
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:14:53 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:26:56 2021
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

When I launch an interactive session for a Windows docker container via `docker run`, the docker container terminal respects my current terminal layout - that is, I can use all rows and columns available in the viewport.

For example, running this command:

`docker run -i --rm mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2`

Yields:

[image: cmd.exe]
[image: powershell.exe]

If I run the same container in docker-compose, the behaviour is different. I only have 80 columns and 25 rows available, which causes overlapping text and cursor-hopping.

For example, using these basic docker-compose.yml files:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2
    command: cmd.exe
```

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2
    command: powershell.exe
```

When launched via:

`docker-compose run --rm test`

Yields:

[image: cmd.exe in docker-compose]
[image: powershell.exe in docker-compose]

Modifying the docker-compose file to include the `stdin_open` and `tty` options as shown below makes no difference.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  test:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2
    command: powershell.exe
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Comment: ever found a solution for this?

Comment: No, sorry, and I've since shifted to Mac (this wasn't the reason!)